# *ngFor adding whitespace to select in Angular form

Tags: angular

Using an *ngFor loop in an Angular form is adding whitespace before and after items in the select. This is causing errors in down-stream code since it makes it hard to patch or set values in the select (i.e. from stored values from the database used to pre-fill the form). Angular version 12.1.4.

If I just manually enter the data in the ion-select this does not occur.

So two questions: Why does this happen and how to get rid of this behaviour?

home.page.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {

  public nameForm = new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    name1: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
  });

  nameList: string[] = ['Louise','Nancy','Kate'];

  constructor(){}

  public onSubmit() {
    console.log("Does name1 have whitespace???", this.nameForm.value);
  }
}
```

home.html

```
<ion-content>

<form [formGroup]="nameForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Choose name</ion-label>
        <ion-select formControlName="name">
          <ion-select-option>Louise</ion-select-option>
          <ion-select-option>Nancy</ion-select-option>
          <ion-select-option>Kate</ion-select-option>
        </ion-select>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Choose name1</ion-label>
      <ion-select formControlName="name1">
        <ion-select-option *ngFor="let n of nameList">
        {{n}}
        </ion-select-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>

  </form>

</ion-content>
```

home.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HomePage } from './home.page';

import { HomePageRoutingModule } from './home-routing.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    HomePageRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [HomePage]
})
export class HomePageModule {}
```

console log output:

> Does name1 have whitespace??? {name: 'Louise', name1: ' Louise '}

Answer (score 1):

Update: I wondered if this was a new line issue in the way I had done the html. And yes, if it is changed to:

```
<ion-select-option *ngFor="let n of nameList">{{n}}</ion-select-option>
```

I get values without whitespace!

> Does name1 have whitespace??? {name: "Louise" name1: "Louise"}